# Swift To Group Images

Tags: ios, swift

I should create what you see in the image. I have an array of images and I should group them. When I click should open a window with all the images. does anyone have any idea?[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to blend to images together into one image? Are you trying to display multiple images in a collection?

Comment: i am trying to display multiple images in a collection. When I click the "+7" should appear other images

Comment: my problem is not group images in a UICollectionView, but realize the view with the "+7" and the animation that shows me the other images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you have no idea I will give a short one. You need a `collectionView` and 2 different `collectionViewCells`.

1. First Collection Cell (containing a `UIImageView`) which will be used to show the image
2. Second Collection Cell will have a `UIImageView`, above it a transparent `UIView` with black color, and above both there should be a an `UILabel` in the middle showing the number of photos that you've not shown.

`UIViewController` should conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` where you need to handle this thing

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // This is the last element where you show the second custom cell
    if indexPath.item == collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        // Load all the items and pass it to the controller that you need to present
    }
}
```

Now good luck at implementing it as it helps you to get better at understanding how things work on `iOS`